# cellForRow returns nil - swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm calling a JSON and saving the data on a array, after that reload the tableView, when i use `dequeueReusableCell` everything works, but when i change to `cellForRow` i get a crash every time i set the cell. The reason im using cellForRow is that i need to change the image of the cell after the user clicks on it but if i use `dequeueReusableCell` i get multiple changes (since the cell is always reused).

I'm getting a crash at the `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TicketTableViewCell`. I already done a search but nothing helped me.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TicketTableViewCell

    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TicketTableViewCell

    cell.date.text = arrDate[indexPath.row].date

    //Top Bottom Space.
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bounds = cell.bounds
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: bounds.width-4, height: bounds.height-4), cornerRadius: 2).cgPath
    cell.layer.mask = maskLayer

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It is obviously give you nil because that cell is never added at `indexPath`, You need to use `dequeueReusableCell` & add the problem of reusing in your question.

Comment: You should use `dequeueReusableCell` in `cellForRowAt`, and `cellForRow` elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the data source method `tableView(:cellForRowAt:)` you can't use `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` because the second method just *gives you back* the cell that you previously gave it in the first method.

It's meant to get back a cell from the table view if you have an index path. You can't get around the table view's view-reuse, you have to use dequeue.

If the problem is you "get multiple changes (since the cell is always reused)" you need to ensure the cell is properly prepared for reuse, and/or that it's only setup once.

I'm not sure what your implementation is, but when your view controller gets called that the user has clicked on the cell (from a button or gesture recognizer) you should pass the cell itself, because if you have the cell you can call `tableview.indexPathForCell()` and know which indexPath was clicked, so you will know what data to update this cell with. Hope this helps.

EDIT: (Cell is 'selected' in the sense you keep track, not the cell's `selected` property, if you want to use that it's all different).  You should also track the currently selected index and format the cell differently in the data source method, in case the user scrolls the selected cell off-screen and back it should still be selected.

Having the data source method check if a cell is selected is important because it would also let you just indiscriminately reload any cells that you think might have a change. But that's not great practice (but simple and fine!) better is if you have the cell you can set its properties directly.

Comment: The problem is that i cant change the last cell image. Lets suppose the user click on cell A (image changes) then click on cell B, the cell A should get the default image since its not select anymore. every time the user click a cell i save the indexPath on a variable, when he clicks another cell i just use the variable to set the image on the cell back to the original state, but this does not work.

Comment: What you've described should be compatible with this. What you've described sounds fine, I'd need to see the code. If you want to return all other cells to the default, a common way is looping over visible cells, `for cell in tableView.visibleCells {` and setting everything to the default, then setting the different value you want. Then you don't need to track which cell was previously selected.

Comment: OK - then you just need to reload the previous row as well, and it will be redrawn, confirm that the selectedIndex is different, and use the default image.

Or it will, once you add some code to `cellForRowAt` to update the cell.  If you're updating the image directly as part of the didSelect method, then you should take that out, update your selectedIndex, and reload the current and previous (where it exists)

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot guys for the fast reply, i already know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Go back to using dequeueReusableCell

in `didSelectRowAt` change the image you want to use, or set a value somewhere in your data set, and reload that row

Make sure that the `cellForRowAt` method uses the updated image or flag that you have set, and redraw the cell.

Comment: Actually i do that but the problem is that i cant change the last cell image. Lets suppose the user click on cell A (image changes) then click on cell B, the cell A should get the default image since its not select anymore. every time the user click a cell i save the indexPath on a variable, when he clicks another cell i just use the variable to set the image on the cell back to the original state, but this does not work.