# cellForRow(at: ) returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have this function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! customCell
    changeCellProperty(selectedIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell;
}

func changeCellProperty(selectedIndexPath: IndexPath){
    print("indexpath = \(selectedIndexPath)") . // printing [0,0] and all values
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) as! customCell    
    // got nil while unwrapping error in above statement.

    cell.label.text = ""
    // and change other properties of cell.
}
```

I am not able to understand the error.
When I am getting the indexpath, then why I am not able to point a particular cell and change properties accordingly.

Comment: copy/past your error log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cellForRow returns nil - swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898389/cellforrow-returns-nil-swift-3)

Comment: Yes, I have added the identifier from interface builder and then used the same here.   The problem is if I made these changes in cellForRowAt indexPath: function ie. changing properties of the cell (title,text etc), everything is running smoothly but I want to make these changes outside the cellForRowAt indexPath: function i.e in my custom function. That is where the problem is arising.

Comment: As per above code, crash will happen when the cell "0" is loading. Because, the method `let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) as! customCell` will return nil for first row.

Comment: First check cell class you have assigned is correct or not, second thing is, if your cell is in XIB then you should register your cell before dequeue.

Comment: @sunny, you are trying to ask the tableview to give you the cell for the index-path __before__ you actually created – however it does not make any sense to create an infinite loop of cross calls – it is safer to change the signature to `changeCellProperty(customCell: CustomCell) { ... }`  and send the half-ready cell to your sub method... or much better to use the [`tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview) to finalise the view/content before appearance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access a cell that has not yet been added to the tableView. That is what you are trying to do here in `changeCellProperty` method. So, if your dequeue works, then all you would need to do is pass the dequeued cell to that method.

```
func changeCellProperty(cell: customCell){
     cell.label.text = ""
     // and change other properties of cell.
}
```

Your `cellForRowAt` method would look like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! customCell
    changeCellProperty(cell: cell)
    return cell
}
```

---

**Note:** class names should be *UpperCamelCase*. So your `customCell` should be named `CustomCell`.

Comment: Solved the issue.  Thanks a lot